# Prolog return certain permutations

Tags: prolog, return, permutation

i have a predicate schedule(A,B,C) that returns possible permutations at lists A,B,C with backtracking

```
?- schedule(A,B,C).

A = [im204,212,217]
B = [im209,214,218]
C = [im210,216] ? ;

A = [im204,212,218]
B = [im209,214,217]
C = [im210,216] ? ;

A = [im204,212,216]
B = [im209,214,218]
C = [im210,217] ?
```

I also have the predicate schedule_errors(A,B,C,E) which returns errors (dont mind what the erros are) from lists A,B,C to E.

```
?- schedule_errors([im204, im209, im210], [im212, im214, im217], [im216, im218]).
E = 4 ?
```

In my new predicate

```
schedule_all_errors(A,B,C,E):-
   schedule(A,B,C),
   schedule_errors(A,B,C,E).
```

it returns possible permutations along with the error number

```
?- schedule_all_errors(A,B,C,E).

A = [im204,212,217]
B = [im209,214,218]
C = [im210,216]
E = 14 ? ;

A = [im204,212,218]
B = [im209,214,217]
C = [im210,216]
E = 6 ? ;

A = [im204,212,216]
B = [im209,214,218]
C = [im210,217]
E = 12 ?
```

I was wondering if there was a way i can return only the permutations with zero errors. (or not return any permutations whose errors are different than 0)

Comment: Why don't you copy paste your query? The images are hard to read for blind people and can not be indexed for search. Imgurl might even take them down at some point.

Comment: sorry, i am new to this , i will keep that in mind :)

Comment: Just edited the pics, have a look at the source to see how source code is embedded (4 spaces or in between backticks)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add this condition in the end

```
schedule_all_errors_1(A,B,C):-
   schedule(A,B,C),
   schedule_errors(A,B,C,E),
   E = 0.
```

or

```
schedule_all_errors_1(A,B,C):-
   schedule(A,B,C),
   schedule_errors(A,B,C,0).
```

Whether the second one will work depends on the definition of `schedule_errors`.

Comment: i feel really stupid...E = 0 condition did the job, thank you